# compare and swap vs test and set

Tags: c++, atomic, thread-synchronization

Could someone explain to me the working and differences of above operations in multi-threading?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`test-and-set` modifies the contents of a memory location and returns its old value as a single atomic operation.

`compare-and-swap` atomically compares the contents of a memory location to a given value and, **only if they are the same**, modifies the contents of that memory location to a given new value.

*The difference marked in bold.*

Comment: Since `compare-and-swap` does more work than `test-and-set` does it take more time than `test-and-set`?

Comment: @arunmoezhi, it depends on implementation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. The reason why I'm interested in this is if test-and-set is faster then I can modify my algorithm to use it instead of compare-and-swap

Comment: Here're some code examples: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4410/2015su/lectures/lec06-spin.html

Answer (score 11):

**Test and set operates on a bit, compare and swap operates on a 32-bit field.**

The z/TPF system favors the use of the test and set (TS) instruction because frequently, lock indicators are bits that are set to control access to critical regions of system code. **The test and set (TS) instruction requires fewer registers than the compare and swap (CS) instruction and requires less execution time because only a single byte needs to be set.**

and, I found these materials from : http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.13/gtpc3/tasinst.html

you can learn more about TSL with the book called "Modern Operating System,Chapter 2"...