# Why CompareAndSwap is more of a powerful instruction than TestAndSet?

Tags: c, locking, mutual-exclusion, compare-and-swap, test-and-set

Please consider the following piece of code for CompareAndSwap and let me know why this atomic instruction is more powerful than atomic TestAndSet for being a mutual exclusion primitive?

```
char CompareAndSwap(int *ptr, int old, int new) {
unsigned char ret;
// Note that sete sets a ’byte’ not the word
__asm__ __volatile__ (
" lock\n"
" cmpxchgl %2,%1\n"
" sete %0\n"
: "=q" (ret), "=m" (*ptr)
: "r" (new), "m" (*ptr), "a" (old)
: "memory");
return ret;
}
```

Comment: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-locks.pdf At the end of page 12.

Comment: @Acme So can we say according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659336/compare-and-swap-vs-test-and-set we have less update to the lock (flag value)? Please correct me if I am wrong! So are we talking of powerfulness in terms of less updates?

Comment: There is a fundamental difference in how they work.In CompareAndSwap there is a comparison and an update happening on getting similar value, in Test-and-set the old value is returned after writing new value, Test-and-set will not have upto date information and hence overwrites each time while CompareAndSwap will and hence will write only if the value is same.

Answer (score 1):

test-and-set modifies the contents of a memory location and returns its old value as a single atomic operation.

compare-and-swap atomically compares the contents of a memory location to a given value and, only if they are the same, modifies the contents of that memory location to a given new value.